# How to make a total estimate calculator using checkboxes and jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Is there anyone here who thinks they can help me solve an estimate calculator issue?

The user clicks on different checkboxes which stores a price value and for each checkbox they click it adds a total price. I got that working. But I cant find a way to give the checkbox a range price to display to the user

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDDB5.png)

This is mine, i put in plane text the range, but the value is actually only the first portion of the range unfortunately and I'm not getting to display the range
[image]

This is what is the code i tried:
`

```
   <p class = "dropdown-details">Includes cost of parts and services for the <u>Engine</u></p>
    <div id = "test"></div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <!--Services with prices-->
        <form action="" method="post" id= "engineRepair-form"  class="price-form">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td class="services-row">
                        
                        <input type="checkbox" name="array[]" id="oil" value="2126.15">
                        <label for="oil">Air Filter</label>
                    </td>
                    <td class = "price">
                    $2,126.15 - $2,622.25
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="service">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="array[]" id="gas" value="1063.08">
                        <label for="gas">Gas Filter</label>
                    </td>
                    <td class = "price">
                    $1,063.08 - $1,275.69
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="service">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="array[]" id="tires" value = "3614.46">
                        <label for="tires">Fuel Filter</label>
                    </td>
                    <td class = "price">
                    $3,614.46 - $4,394.05
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <tr>
                    <td class="service">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="array[]" id="sparkPlug" value = "5244.51">
                        <label for="sparkPlug">Spark Plug</label>
                    </td>
                    <td class = "price">
                    $5,244.51 - $6,449.33
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <tr>
                    <td class="service">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="array[]" id="belt_chain" value = "9355.07">
                        <label for="belt_chain">Timing Belt/Chain</label>
                    </td>
                    <td class = "price">
                    $9,355.07 - $1,1410.35
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <tr>
                    <td class="service">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="array[]" id="belt_drive" value = "3685.33">
                        <label for="belt_drive">Fan Belt/Drive Belt</label>
                    </td>
                    <td class = "price">
                    $3,685.33 - $4,323.18
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <tr>
                    <td class="service">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="array[]" id="radiatorHoseSet" value = "7228.92">
                        <label for="radiatorHoseSet">Radiator Hose Set</label>
                    </td>
                    <td class = "price">
                    $7,228.92 - $8,858.97
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="service">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="array[]" id="radiator" value = "27214.74">
                        <label for="radiator">Radiator</label>
                    </td>
                    <td class = "price">
                    $27,214.74 - $33,309.71
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
```

`

Javascrip:
`

```
$(function() {
  $('input').click(function() {
    var total = 0;
    $('input:checked').each(function(index, item) {
      total += parseFloat(item.value);
    });
    $('#test').text(total.toFixed(2));
  });
});
```

`

As you can see, the prices did add but it didn't display the range as showed in the first image I sent. It's supposed to display the total estimated price range

[enter link description here](https://codepen.io/360hazzy/pen/JjZJKNR?editors=1011)

this is also the codepen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, please do not use the `table` tag for layout. It should be used for tabular data only. Its use for layout went out of style at the turn of the century!

Now, onto the problem at hand. As you've discovered, checkboxes can only have one value. We are going to leverage [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to give your more.

```js
$(function() {
  $('input').click(function() {
    var minTotal = 0;
    var maxTotal = 0
    $('input:checked').each(function(index, item) {
      //Add the value from the minval data attribute
      minTotal += parseFloat(item.dataset.minval);
      //Add the value from the maxval data attribute
      maxTotal += parseFloat(item.dataset.maxval); 
    });
    //Update the text field
    $('#test').text("$" + minTotal.toFixed(2) + " - $" + maxTotal.toFixed(2) );
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="dropdown-details">Includes cost of parts and services for the <u>Engine</u></p>
<div id="test"></div>
</div>
<br>
<!--Services with prices-->
<form action="" method="post" id="engineRepair-form" class="price-form">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="services-row">
        <input type="checkbox" name="array[]" id="oil" data-minval="2126.15" data-maxval="2622.25" value="skuOil">
        <label for="oil">Air Filter</label>
      </td>
      <td class="price">
        $2,126.15 - $2,622.25
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="service">
        <input type="checkbox" name="array[]" data-minval="1063.08" data-maxval="1275.69" id="gas" value="skuGas">
        <label for="gas">Gas Filter</label>
      </td>
      <td class="price">
        $1,063.08 - $1,275.69
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is this Answer
i used parentElement and NextSilbiling

```
$(function() {
  $('input').click(function() {
    var total1 = 0;
    var total2 = 0;
    $('input:checked').each(function(index, item) {
      var items = item.parentElement.nextElementSibling.innerText.replace(/[$, ]/g,'').split("-");
      total1 += Number(items[0]);
      total2 += Number(items[1]);
    });
    $('#costOutput').text('$'+total1.toFixed(2)+' - '+ '$'+total2.toFixed(2));
  });
});
```

https://bokboot.net/read?id=47&key=b3897fd0-315c-410d-ab2a-f61b8e8c4a4a

Copy and Paste in your project

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged, please summarise the article and relate it to the original question.

Comment: OMG THANKS A LOT THAT WORKED! i am so excited for your help as well as the other guy's help. Im new to jquery and vanilla js I've only taken a basic course and most of what you guys sent here makes no sense to me haha, the methods that is example:

@ryuhojin sent methods like parseElement(), nextElementSibling(), innerText(), split(), Number() and toFixed()

JonP sent methods like dataset(), minval(), maxval() and parseFloat();

For ease of seeing this message I will just copy and paste this message to the both of you, also I'm kinda new to posting on stack, forgive me. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: i am now going to watch some courses on those methods that you guys sent, thank you, how do I mark this forum as answered?